# Is "Async" keyword the only requirement to make NLog logging asynchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, nlog

I am writing to a target database. In my targets section, I have marked async as true. Do I still need to write code to my web service to make logging async or framework takes care of it?

```xml
<targets async="true">
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target) appears to answer this question. If it doesn't, it would be best to point out (in your question) what you've seen that indicates it's not working.

Comment: I did not understand whether I just need to write ```async``` keyword in the config. Or I also need to implement ```write``` method. Kindly clarify.

Comment: <targets async="true"> is short hand for wrapping all your targets with the AsyncWrapper.  Documentation is suggesting that if your wite() methods take a long time, either set the async or use AsyncWrapper to speed up the writes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, only the async attribute is needed (in your config)

The `async` keyword in C# isn't needed.

PS: Be aware that the async attribute will discard by default if you write more then 10000 events in a short time. If you need more control, then use the asyncWrapper instead of the async attribute. See [docs](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target#remarks)